# Does Realm DB optimise filter calculations on datasets that have not changed?

Tags: swift, database, optimization, realm

From the **Realm** [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/):

```
let puppies = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age < 2")
```

If I call this operation (**filter**("age < 2")) on the same object set (e.g. Dog.self), will Realm **optimise this**?

In other words, once a filter operation is called, does Realm keep track of the result and re-use it (saving computational time) if the database has not changed?

This should result in two different computing times (first time should take longer, second time quicker) - even though the time difference will be minimal for small datasets with today's average computing power, but could be significant for larger data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if no changes have been performed Realm will reuse the existing results. If there were related changes Realm will update the result of the query automatically.

Comment: Cool thank you Dimitry. It makes sense. They probably have an internal data-structure that they use to keep track of these queries. Would be interesting to find out more about the technical implementation of this as well as the performance. I guess I could just test it myself, but would take long to build proper stats. Have you any more details that you can add as reference to this in your answer?

Comment: Realm Core and other parts are fully open sourced, so you can check out all the implementation details: https://github.com/realm/realm-core ;)